# texture baking problem

Tags: uv, texture-baking, error

I have 2 textures, I put them on the object and edited it with uv. After that, I baked them, but to me the cherry was such a thing! why is that ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like overlapping UVs. But I am not entirely sure if that is correct. You might want to check your UV wunrapping and see if there are some parts that overlap. If they do: Remove the overlapping side of the UV and bake it again.

Answer (score 1):

1. In a 3D View editor, select a mesh and enter UV/Face Select mode.
2. Unwrap the mesh object.
3. In a UV/Image Editor, either create a new image or open an existing one. If your 3D View is in textured display mode, you should now see the image mapped to your mesh. Ensure that all faces are selected.
4. In the Bake panel at the bottom of the Render menu, bake your desired type of image (Full Render, etc.).
5. When rendering is complete, Blender replaces the image with the Baked image.
6. Save the image.
7. Apply the image to the mesh as a UV texture. For displacement and normal maps, refer to Bump and Normal Maps. For full and texture bakes, refer to Textures.
8. Refine the image using the process described below, or embellish with Texture Paint or an external image editor.

### [Blender manual BAKE](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/bake.html)

### your target object must have a UVmap already ordered

[image: uv target]

### do not forget the lights

[image: lights]

### select BAKE TEXTURE

[image: BAKE]